# Verified go signature in solidity (EIP712 TypedData)

Tags: go-ethereum, signature, golang

I am trying to recover the signer of a TypedData message (eip712).

I am able to sign and verify with ethersJS and validate in the contract as well.

With Go, I can sign and verify as well but the verification fail in the contract.

**Turn out this code is working fine.**

**The TypedData;**

```
signerData := TypedData{
        Types: Types{
            "Quote": []Type{
                {Name: "cost", Type: "uint256"},
                {Name: "deadline", Type: "uint256"},
            },
            "EIP712Domain": []Type{
                {Name: "name", Type: "string"},
                {Name: "chainId", Type: "uint256"},
                {Name: "version", Type: "string"},
                {Name: "verifyingContract", Type: "string"},
                {Name: "salt", Type: "string"},
            },
        },
        PrimaryType: "Quote",
        Domain: TypedDataDomain{
            Name:              "MyDomain",
            Version:           "1",
            ChainId:           ethMath.NewHexOrDecimal256(ChainId.Int64()),
            VerifyingContract: contractAddress.String(),
            Salt:              "0",
        },
        Message: TypedDataMessage{
            "cost":     "0",          
            "deadline": "1659095005", 
        },
    }
```

**Encoding the data;**

```
func EncodeForSigning(typedData TypedData) (hash common.Hash, err error) {
    domainSeparator, err := typedData.HashStruct("EIP712Domain", typedData.Domain.Map())

    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    typedDataHash, err := typedData.HashStruct(typedData.PrimaryType, typedData.Message)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    rawData := []byte(fmt.Sprintf("\x19\x01%s%s", string(domainSeparator), string(typedDataHash)))
    hash = common.BytesToHash(crypto.Keccak256(rawData))
    return
}
```

**Sign TypedData;**

```
func (s Signer) SignTypedData(typedData TypedData) (sig []byte, err error) {
    hash, err := EncodeForSigning(typedData)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    sig, err = crypto.Sign(hash.Bytes(), s.key)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    
    sig[64] += 27

    return
}
```

I am able to verify it in Go;

```
func Ecrecover(hash, signature []byte) (addr common.Address, err error) {
    sig := make([]byte, len(signature))
    copy(sig, signature)
    if len(sig) != 65 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("invalid length of signture: %d", len(sig))
        return
    }

    if sig[64] != 27 && sig[64] != 28 && sig[64] != 1 && sig[64] != 0 {
        err = fmt.Errorf("invalid signature type")
        return
    }
    if sig[64] >= 27 {
        sig[64] -= 27
    }

    recoverPub, err := crypto.Ecrecover(hash, sig)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("can not ecrecover: %v", err)
        return
    }
    pubKey, err := crypto.UnmarshalPubkey(recoverPub)
    if err != nil {
        err = fmt.Errorf("can not unmarshal pubkey: %v", err)
        return
    }

    addr = crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*pubKey)
    return
}
```

However in the contract it fails, I have tried with ECDSA and _hashTypedDataV4, they both return the same address but it is wrong.

```
function validateQuote(uint256 _cost,uint256 _deadline, bytes memory _signature) public view returns (address) {

        Quote memory quote = Quote({
            cost: _cost,
            deadline: _deadline
        });

        bytes32 msghash = _hashTypedDataV4(hash(quote));

        uint8 v;
        bytes32 r;
        bytes32 s;

         (v, r, s) = splitSignature(_signature);

        (address signer, ) = ECDSA.tryRecover(msghash,_signature);

        console.log("v4 signer", signer);
        console.log("v", v);

        return (verifyQuote(quote, v,r,s)); 
    }
```

The Hexadecimal representation of the signature is the same in go and in solidity, however the signer returned by solidity is not valid.

V = 27

The go validation return the correct address

```
//validate signature
hash, err = EncodeForSigning(signerData)
signerAddress, err := Ecrecover(hash.Bytes(), sig)

fmt.Println("Signer Recovery", signerAddress) // good
```

What would be the cause of the failure on the contract side?

I was able to validate that same signature with Ethers where V=28
The same signature with go set's V to 27. Not sure it's related.

Comment: Any update on this? I am also facing same issue locally signing and verification is all good but contract side, verification is failing.

Comment: Same here also failing on contract side

Answer (score 0):

```
ethers.utils.splitSignature(signature).compact
```

You can try this with ether.js after generating the signature with go.I'm not sure if it works, but you can try it.